# Same Solr search queries returning different results

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

From reading the docs the search `+term +another_term` should return the same documents as `term AND another_term`. But I'm getting different results. Someone suggested that one of the terms is actually acting as an OR. But I thought the search queries were baked into SOLR.

Where in the Solr config would I check for this?

Comment: Are you literally typing in: term + another_term (with the + as an operator?)

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, it should have been term AND another_term. Fixed in the post above.

Comment: which QueryParser are you using? (e.g., Standard, DisMax, etc.)

Comment: Via the Solr Admin Debug utility, can you check how the relevance for the results are calculated?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the debug flat in the admin UI when you run those two queries, it will show you what they get translated to on the lowest level after the Query Parser, etc. You can compare and see if something is different.